# Oracle: Mixing NVL with Outer Join

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got the following query.

The only "left" table is the one with the alias "o".

I want to specify the following. How can I do? Should I use a WITH temp construct?

```
AND (   NVL (domb.DOMB_CONTO_CORRENTE, ' ') != o.campo43
OR NVL (abi.abi_descrizione, ' ') != o.campo41
OR NVL (cab.cab_descrizione, ' ') != o.campo42)
```

Here's the complete statement:

```
  SELECT /*+ parallel(o 64) */
        o.stato, COUNT (1)
    FROM CONF_RAGGRUPPAMENTI_FORN rgf,
         CRD_RID_REL_DOMICILIAZIONE crrd,
         CRD_DOMICILIAZIONI domb,
         uff_abi abi,
         uff_abi_cab cab,
         CONTO_CLIENTE_T809 o,
         eni_flussi_hub c,
         eni_monitor mon
   WHERE     1 = 1
         --RGF - OUT
         AND rgf.RGF_CODICE_RAGGRUPPAMENTO(+) = o.campo1
         --Join tra OUT e la ENI_FLUSSI_HUB
         AND o.id_messaggio = c.flh_id_messaggio(+)
         AND o.d_pubblicazione = c.flh_data_elaborazione(+)
         --Join tra ENI_FLUSSI_HUB e ENI_MONITOR
         AND c.FLH_ID_MESSAGGIO = MON.MON_ID_MESSAGGIO(+)
         AND c.FLH_TIPO_PROCESSO_COD = MON.MON_COD_TP_PROCESSO(+)
         AND c.flh_flag_ann(+) = 'N'
         AND mon_flag_ann(+) = 'N'
         --Join da RGF a DOMB
         AND rgf.UITR_IDENT_TIPI_RAGGR_ID(+) = 'MP'
         AND rgf.RGF_RAGGRUPPAMENTO_FORN_ID = crrd.RGF_RAGGRUPPAMENTO_FORN_ID(+)
         AND crrd.DOMB_DOMICILIAZIONE_ID = domb.DOMB_DOMICILIAZIONE_ID(+)
         AND CRRD.CRRD_RID_REL_DOM_ID = crrd.crrd_storico_id
         AND CRRD.CRRD_FLAG_ANN (+) = 'N'
         AND domb.domb_flag_ann (+) = 'N'
         AND rgf.rgf_flag_ann(+) = 'N'
         --Join tra domb e abi e cab
         AND DOMB.ABI_ID = abi.ABI_ID(+)
         AND DOMB.CAB_ID = cab.CAB_ID(+)
         --Filtro sulle date
         AND o.d_pubblicazione BETWEEN TO_DATE ('06-apr-2013')
                                   AND TO_DATE ('14-apr-2013')
         --Solo i flussi che producono variazioni
         AND (   NVL (domb.DOMB_CONTO_CORRENTE, ' ') != o.campo43
              OR NVL (abi.abi_descrizione, ' ') != o.campo41
              OR NVL (cab.cab_descrizione, ' ') != o.campo42)
GROUP BY o.stato
```

Comment: What version of oracle are you on?

Comment: @Gik25 : I'd recommend to stop using 20 years old (and non-standard) syntax for `LEFT JOIN`. In addition to improved readability, you will be able to write more flexible conditions in natural way...

Comment: @a1ex07 While Oracle does say so in their own documentation -- see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries006.htm#sthref3298 -- it doesn't always work. See this blog entry http://databaseperformance.blogspot.se/2012/07/all-outer-joins-are-not-equal.html for reasons why you may sometimes wish to fallback to using the old Oracle-specific syntax. Basically it has to do with how Oracle converts these queries into its own internal format for execution. This may not always be optimal and may prevent the usage of indexes in certain cases.

Comment: Using a with is almost always a good idea -- it can improve the readability of your queries.

Comment: @Colin 't Hart :I'm not sure I follow your point. In the link you provided it says "Oracle recommends that you use the FROM clause OUTER JOIN syntax rather than the Oracle join operator", and old syntax has many restrictions, not vice verse. Internal conversions (if any) are part of implementation, and I doubt the second article mentioned in your comment properly describes how it happens on physical level. Usage (or lack of it) of indexes is optimizer job, and in a very few cases when it cannot do find the best plan, hints can help; but not "+".

Comment: Read the blog -- and the blog it referencescwritten by the Oracle optimizer team themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can, I would recommend rewriting your query in modern ANSI syntax. This makes the query not only more readable, but it's easier to apply predicates on the optional table in a clear manner. I've rewritten 'old' Oracle queries and it's usually a quick cut and paste job to move the join conditions from the `WHERE` clause to the `FROM ... JOIN ... ON ...` clause.

Then, any predicates that apply to the optional table are listed under the `OUTER JOIN` condition, not under the `WHERE`. For example (in a **very** rough example):

```
SELECT 
  mt.col1, 
  mt.col2, 
  ot.col3
  -- other columns ...
FROM main_table mt
LEFT OUTER JOIN optional_table ot ON mt.col1 = ot.col1 
  AND ot.col2 = 'N' 
  AND NVL (ot.some_column, 'x') != mt.col5
-- Now the where for the result set and main table
WHERE
 AND mt.col4 BETWEEN TO_DATE ('06-apr-2013') AND TO_DATE ('14-apr-2013')
-- Other conditions on the total result set.
```

I've found this easiest way to apply conditions to the optional table without excluding rows from the final set.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use the + on the NVLs because you establish the outer join already on the ID of domp, abi, and cab.

I agree with the others that using JOIN statement makes more readable SQL Selects.

Do you have any trouble with the query?

Comment: Thank you. Are you sure about your first sentence?

Comment: Actually yes, because I assume that the ID's are already giving the link because they act as primary / foreign key. Basically you can easily check this. When you do not use them, you can see that you just have some unique rows too much. Then you further reduce the result set with the extra where. It is much clearer if you use the other syntax. In the `LEFT JOIN ON` I am always only connecting the keys and then in the `WHERE` clause I add the additional selection criteria. I am very sure (under the assumption I just mentioned)